# Date difference in mysql for each row

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I want to get te difference in seconds for each datetime row. How can I achieve this in mysql?

```
id record
1 2019-02-12 19:59:44
2 2019-02-12 20:00:27
3 2019-02-12 20:01:10
```

Desired Output:

```
id record               difference in seconds
1  2019-02-12 19:59:44  0
2  2019-02-12 20:00:27  43
3  2019-02-12 20:01:10  44
```

Comment: Which MySQL version? You are going to need to use MySQL 8 `LAG()` or emulate/simulate that with MySQL user variables or a co-related subquery, stackoverflow should have duplicates already for this kind of question.

Comment: MySql Version 8.0.12, I already search a lot and there isn't any question of this specific kind, the stuff here is for each row, if the difference were for each column was more easy..

Comment: *"I already search a lot and there isn't any question of this specific kind, the stuff here is for each row, if the difference were for each column was more easy."* i've posted a answer but i doubt them if i interpected your question correctly now i read your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most easy is to convert to a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` on which you can directly calculate.

You can directly calculate between the current record and the `LAG()` one like.

`column - LAG(column) OVER()` 
`column + LAG(column) OVER()`

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   t.id
 , t.record
 , (
     CASE 
       WHEN 
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.record) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(t.record) OVER(ORDER BY t.record ASC)) IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.record) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(t.record) OVER(ORDER BY t.record ASC))
       ELSE 0
     END
   ) AS difference_in_seconds                                                                      
FROM 
 t
ORDER BY 
  t.id ASC
```

**Result**

```
| id  | record              | difference_in_seconds |
| --- | ------------------- | --------------------- |
| 1   | 2019-02-12 19:59:44 | 0                     |
| 2   | 2019-02-12 20:00:27 | 43                    |
| 3   | 2019-02-12 20:01:10 | 43                    |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c9tqh3JLvY3B5YUB6qu4T1/1)

> Why repeating yourself in the CASE expression? Use COALESCE

Indeed

```
COALESCE(
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.record) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(t.record) OVER(ORDER BY t.record ASC))
     , 0                                                                  
   ) AS difference_in_seconds
```

is the same as using

```
 (
     CASE 
       WHEN 
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.record) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(t.record) OVER(ORDER BY t.record ASC)) IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 
          UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.record) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(t.record) OVER(ORDER BY t.record ASC))
       ELSE 0
     END
   ) AS difference_in_seconds
```

Comment: Why repeating yourself in the CASE expression? Use COALESCE.

Comment: Work's perfectly! Thank you

Comment: *"Why repeating yourself in the CASE expression? Use COALESCE"* Good question @PaulSpiegel low coffee levels i believe and didn't think about `COALESCE()`